# Check if the unique constraint exists and drop it using liquibase

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I have a changeset wherein I initially check if the unique constraint exists and then if it does it will drop the constraint.

```
<changeSet author="loren"
               id="DROP_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_RULEPRIORITY_ORACLE_v1" dbms="oracle">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <sqlCheck expectedResult="1">
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
                WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='UC_RULES_PRIORITY'
            </sqlCheck>
        </preConditions>
        <dropUniqueConstraint constraintName="UC_RULES_PRIORITY"
                              schemaName="${main.schema}"
                              tableName="RULES"/>

</changeSet>
```

The issue with this is it does not seem to pass the precondition. It always says MARK_RAN meaning there was no constraint found. In turn, the constraint will never be dropped.

I have tried executing the SELECT statement in my db and it returns 1.

Is this the correct way or is there an alternate solution for this?

Comment: Is `${main.schema}` different from the current user? What if you use `all_constraints` and include the owner in the where clause?

Comment: Are you referring to this type of usage of ${main.schema}?


SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM ${main.schema}.USER_CONSTRAINTS          WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='UC_RULES_PRIORITY'

Comment: No. Replace `user_constraints` with `all_constraints`. And again: is `${main.schema}` the same as the user you use to connect to Oracle?

Comment: I used all_constraints and it works now. Thanks. And yes, ${main.schema} is the same as the one I use to connect to Oracle.

Comment: If `${main.schema}` is indeed the same as the username then `user_constraints` should work just the same as `all_constraitns`. Did you include the `owner` as a `where` condition when using `all_constraints`?  If not then, you might have checked the constraint for a different user. Most probably `${main.schema}` is **not** the same as the useranme then.

Comment: You're right I have added the owner to the SELECT statement. Thanks again. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS              WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='UC_RULES_PRIORITY' AND OWNER='${main.schema}'

Comment: If that statement works, then you are not using Oracle. Oracle has no `information_schema`

Comment: Oops. I pasted the wrong statement. Here's the correct one: SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
                WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='UC_RULES_PRIORITY'
                AND OWNER='${main.schema}'

Comment: The sqlCheck will not work as you expect if the UC_RULES_PRIORITY constraint is not associated with a column.  A unique key is a type of unique constraint, but there are other types of unique constraints as well.  
If you use the following SQL to check if the constraint exists, it should solve your problem:  
                               SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS ucc JOIN USER_CONSTRAINTS uc ON ucc.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
WHERE uc.constraint_name='UC_RULES_PRIORITY' AND uc.table_name = 'RULES' AND uc.constraint_type = 'U' ;

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments:

```
<changeSet author="loren"
               id="DROP_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_RULEPRIORITY_ORACLE_v1" dbms="oracle">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <sqlCheck expectedResult="1">
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM all_constraints
                WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='UC_RULES_PRIORITY'
                AND OWNER='${main.schema}'
            </sqlCheck>
        </preConditions>
        <dropUniqueConstraint constraintName="UC_RULES_PRIORITY"
                              schemaName="${main.schema}"
                              tableName="RULES"/>

</changeSet>
```

@Loren: please adjust and/or post your own answer.